# CKEditor Unable to Clean up Copied Paste Text From Word?

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor4.x

I have copied text from word document and paste it into CKEditor 4.11.2 on my local PC. When I view source in editor the document does not clean up well. Here what I see in my editor source view:

```
<p><span style="font-family:Khmer OS Muol">ព្រះរាជាណាចក្រកម្ពុជា</span></p>

<p><span style="font-family:Khmer OS Muol">ជាតិ សាសនា ព្រះមហាក្សត្រ</span></p>

<p></p>

<p><span style="font-family:Khmer OS Muol">ល</span><span style="font-family:Khmer OS Muol">.</span><span style="font-family:Khmer OS Muol">រ</span><span style="font-family:Khmer OS Muol">............................</span></p>

<p><span style="font-family:Khmer OS Muol">កិច្ចសន្យាដាក់ធានាកាតព្វកិច្ច</span></p>

<p><span style="font-family:Khmer Kep"><strong>១</strong></span><span style="font-family:Khmer Kep"><strong>. </strong></span><span style="font-family:Khmer Kep"><strong>ឈ្មោះ និងអាសយដ្ឋានរបស់ភាគីនៃកិច្ចសន្យា</strong></span><span style="font-family:Khmer Kep"><strong> </strong></span></p>

<p><span style="font-family:Khmer Kep"><strong>(</strong></span><span style="font-family:Khmer Kep"><strong>១</strong></span><span style="font-family:Khmer Kep"><strong>)</strong></span><span style="font-family:Khmer Kep"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></span><span style="font-family:Khmer Kep"><strong>ម្ចាស់បំណុល</strong></span><span style="font-family:Khmer Kep"><strong>&nbsp; </strong></span><span style="font-family:Khmer Kep"><strong>ឬ</strong></span><span style="font-family:Khmer Kep"><strong> &nbsp;</strong></span><span style="font-family:Khmer Kep"><strong>អ្នកទទួលការដាក់ធានាកាតព្វកិច្</strong></span><span style="font-family:Khmer Kep"><strong>ច</strong></span><span style="font-family:Khmer Kep"><strong> </strong></span><span style="font-family:Khmer Kep"><strong>:</strong></span><span style="font-family:Khmer Kep"><strong> &nbsp;</strong></span><span style="font-family:Khmer Kep"><strong>គ្រឹះស្ថានមីក្រូហិរញ្ញវត្ថុ</strong></span></p>
```

However, the same document I copied paste on [CKEditor example](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/examples/uicolor.html),in the source view, it clean up my document really well as below:

```
<p>ព្រះរាជាណាចក្រកម្ពុជា</p>

<p>ជាតិ សាសនា ព្រះមហាក្សត្រ</p>

<p></p>

<p>ល.រ............................</p>

<p>កិច្ចសន្យាដាក់ធានាកាតព្វកិច្ច</p>

<p><strong>១</strong><strong>. </strong><strong>ឈ្មោះ និងអាសយដ្ឋានរបស់ភាគីនៃកិច្ចសន្យា</strong><strong> </strong></p>

<p><strong>(</strong><strong>១</strong><strong>)</strong><strong>&nbsp;</strong><strong>ម្ចាស់បំណុល</strong><strong>&nbsp; </strong><strong>ឬ</strong><strong> &nbsp;</strong><strong>អ្នកទទួលការដាក់ធានាកាតព្វកិច្</strong><strong>ច</strong><strong> </strong><strong>:</strong><strong> &nbsp;</strong><strong>គ្រឹះស្ថានមីក្រូហិរញ្ញវត្ថុ</strong></p>
```

I'm wondering how I can cleanup copied and paste text as above, as I have searched around and tried below config as I found but it still does not works

```
    config.pasteFromWordPromptCleanup = true;
    config.pasteFromWordRemoveFontStyles = true;
    config.pasteFromWordRemoveStyles = true;
```

Comment: Download and try a jQuery function to make just that. You can find it here https://gist.github.com/sbrin/6801034

Comment: You're better off detecting paste-from-word and stopping the user from saving the file. Word docs are such a mess. You end up with encoding problems, nested redundant tags, inline styles that can't be overridden and other nasty surprises.

Comment: @Pluda, thanks, how can I integrate it in ckeditor? I don't want to use it as a separate module. One more, why `pastefromword` plugin does not work, it is supposed to perform its task for this work.

Comment: @HouyNarun, I’m sorry, can’t help you with that, I never used ckeditor. When I read your topic title I remember about this plugin and shared with you. You can’t avoid people from pasting whatever they like in ckeditor, so you should clean html after they submit. So you’ll have to search in ckeditor documentation what happens on submit and apply the plugin at that moment.

Comment: @Pluda, Thanks anyway for your contribution and help, I'm really appreciate, it just mean I not yet configure out how to do. my purpose is to create web application form from the given ms word document that's why I choose this editor. Regards

Comment: if you want to go deeper in this consider build your own editor, sample simple code here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Editable_content

Comment: then you need to understand how cut/copy paste work, here is a good starting point https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Interact_with_the_clipboard , after that you can integrate the plugin